# Executing a procedure only at the last-returning callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I have this piece of code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++){
    some_array[i].asynchronous_function(some, parameter, callback(){
         some_procedure();
    });
}
```

I call `asynchronous_function` for each element of the array, and once the function executed, it fires a callback. I have some procedure in the callback that I would like to execute *only* if this callback is the last one returning of all the `asynchronous_function`s called. Is there a way to achieve this without polluting too much the code?

Thanks

Comment: Pass a parameter to your callback to indicate whether this is the last one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

count the number of times `asynchronous_function` is called. when it has been called some_array.length times, you can call some_procedure(). something like this

```
var numTimesCalled = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++){
    some_array[i].asynchronous_function(some, parameter, function(){
         numTimesCalled ++;
         if (numTimesCalled === some_array.length) {
             some_procedure()
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you just want `numTimesCalled === some_array.length`. Don't subtract 1.

Comment: "There are two hard problems in computer science: Naming things, cache expiration, and off-by-one errors."

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the heads up on the `-1`. Apparently it works fine :-).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job :

```
// callAll : calls methodName method of all array items.
//               uses the provided arguments for the call and adds the callback
//               methodName is async and must accept a callback as last argument
//               lastCallBack will get called once after all methods ended. 
//
function callAll(anArray, methodName, lastCallBack ) {
   // create closure to keep count of calls
   var callCount = anArrray.length;
   // build function that calls lastCallBack on last call
   var callIfLast = function() { callCount--; if (!callCount) lastCallBack(); };
   // build function arguments
   var args = arguments.slice(3).push(callIfLast);
   // call all functions
   anArray.forEach( function(item) { item[methodName].apply(item, args ) } );
 }

callAll(myArray, 'meth', myCallback, 1, 2, 3);
// ...
// --> will call myArray[i].meth(1, 2, 3, callIfLast)  for all i.
//          and call myCallBack when all calls finished.
```